# How to find out client process ID in SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I am using SQL Server Profiler to view my database activities. In that, I want to find out which Client Process ID is associate with which machine (From where application is running).
because there are multiple instance of my application are running on different machines. So I want to identify them.
So is there any way to find out ClientProcessID?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use hostname in profiler, it is the same as the host_name() function in T-SQL

run this in a query window

```
SELECT host_name()
```

In profiler it is hostname, you have to check "show all columns" to see it